# PHP: @fopen() and getimagesize(): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden

Tags: php, facebook, image, filestream

I'm trying to validate `Facebook photos(public)` image URL using `fopen()` and `getimagesize()` on **cloud9 vm,** `fopen()` function returns a null value and getimagesize() throws an error

> "failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden"

, both functions works perfectly for other image URL's.

I've tried to use both functions to validate Facebook image URLs on my localhost wamp server and they seems to be working fine. `allow_url_fopen` is On in **php.ini on c9 server,** is it possible that c9 vm's are blocked by Facebook or am i doing something wrong?

Here's my Validation Function

```
function validateImage($url)
{
    $params = array('http' => array(
        'method' => 'HEAD'
    ));
    $ctx = stream_context_create($params);
    $fp = @fopen($url, 'rb', false, $ctx);
    if (!$fp)
        return false;  // Problem with url

    $meta = stream_get_meta_data($fp);
    if ($meta === false)
    {
        fclose($fp);
        return false;  // Problem reading data from url
    }

    $wrapper_data = $meta["wrapper_data"];
    if(is_array($wrapper_data)){
        foreach(array_keys($wrapper_data) as $hh){
            if (substr($wrapper_data[$hh], 0, 19) == "Content-Type: image") // strlen("Content-Type: image") == 19
            {
                fclose($fp);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    fclose($fp);
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested with a valid image url, but fopen get instead a reference to an image (in my case id #5), not the content. So my advice is to use:
      $img = **file_get_contents**($url);

Now what can you do:

```
  $img = file_get_contents($url);
  if(strlen($img) !==0) {
  echo "good";
      if(substr($img,0,3) === "\xFF\xD8\xFF"){
      echo "It's a jpg !\n";
       }
      else "other type\n";
   }
```

Comment: I'm developing the application over HTTPS, so i guess it is not the issue!

Comment: file_get_contents() function is also throwing the same error "failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden "

Comment: If both fail with Error 403, it seems your VM has problems accessing connections. If even curl raise an error, then you must check rules to connect outside (like firewall, nat against bridge connection) etc.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `is_file($filename)` condition before `getimagesize($filename)` worked for me

```
if(is_file($filename) && getimagesize($filename)) {
  // your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code, it works fine

```
try {
    @ini_set('user_agent', 'Mozilla/5.0');
} catch (Exception $exc) {
    echo $exc->getTraceAsString();
}
```